# Python Selenium get text inside jacascript input

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the bellow code and i want to extract the text in the parenthesis i.e '/team/barcelona/SKbpVP5K/'

```
<span class="team_name_span">
<a onclick="javascript:getUrlByWinType('/team/barcelona/SKbpVP5K/');">Barcelona</a></span>
```

Any way to do that?

best regards,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Below will print `javascript:getUrlByWinType('/team/barcelona/SKbpVP5K/');`.  Assuming you define your driver and go the the url first. In my opinion trimming stings is a separate question but if needed I can add to this answer to help with that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//span[@class='team_name_span']//a")))
text_i_want = element.get_attribute("onclick")
print(text_i_want)
```